# Search functionality in a lightbox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, lightbox

I have a page on which there is a link search.
onclicking search i open a LIGHTBOX where i get a textfield  and Search button.
Now i want  when i enter keyword in textfield and enter on submit button a result should be shown in a lighbox only.
is it possible w/o ajax or i have to use ajax form only.

just curious why we used **get request**  instead of **post request** for Search functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you want not change you page, you need made an ajax request. But you can avoid the ajax request if you lightbox see a frame. In this case, you just define the page. and no need Ajax. But the Frame is not really a good practice.

About why GET request instead POST request is about bookmarking your research. If you want that user can be bookmark a specialy keywords, you can't it's in a post. Not if it's in GET.